# I am getting some text alignment issues when there are multiple TextViews in a horizontal LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, textview, android-linearlayout

In my Main Layout I have a ListView. When a button is clicked it inflates a row that has four TextViews side by side(see image link below) into the ListView.  The problem is that sometimes when any of the TextView text lengths differ from the row above or below, it throws off the text alignment of that row.

Using the first row as an example of what I would like the rest of the rows to look like, I do not understand why the alignment of the Quantity on rows 2,3,5, and 6 has to be moved over just because the Total Bft has the extra characters or why the Description on row 2 and 6 appear to look more centered than the others.  Using the Quantity column as an example I would think that setting the 'gravity' to be 'right' would set all of the texts in that column all the way to the right of the TextView no matter what the length of the text is in the column beside it.  The same goes for the Description.

Basically all I would like is for each of the TextViews text to start at the same spot at the row above it. The image link below demonstrates what I am hoping for.  I have already tried to set the textAllignment property for the TextViews but that did not help me. Also I realize that I could round up some of the decimals or add .000 to the ones without decimals and that would solve some of the issues but I am trying not to do that.
What would be the best way to go about fixing this issue?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8SWt.jpg)

Here is the axml for the LinearLayout and TextViews

```
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBackground">
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtItemNo"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:text="item" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="description"
                android:singleLine="false" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:id="@+id/txtQuantity"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="qty" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:id="@+id/txtTotal"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="total" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should use `width=0dp` with weights

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thank you.  @DavidMedenjak